# Perl - Join Elements of array till a specified length

Tags: arrays, string, perl, join

I have an array of strings say whose length can be anywhere from 1 to 20.
I need to join the 1st 3 elements of array into a string. I used.

```
@a = ("Hello","world","welcome");
$b = join(":",@a[0..2])
```

This produces desired output **Hello:World:welcome**

But When the length of the array is less than 3 say `@a = ("hello","wolrd")`

I get **Hello:world:** as output. If I have 1 variable I get `Hello::` as the output.

I want to restrict joining based on the array's length. Is there any way out to do this?

Comment: Please note that`$b` (and `$a`) are reserved variables for `sort`, you shouldn't use them in code. Also remember to `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With List::Util 1.50 or newer you get the [head](https://perldoc.pl/List::Util#head) function which is nice for this sort of thing, as it will only return up to the number of elements in the list.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 1.50 'head';
my @array = ('hello', 'world');
my $joined = join ':', head 3, @array; # hello:world
```

The [splice](https://perldoc.pl/functions/splice) function can serve as a poor-man's head/tail, but it requires an array specifically and will remove the returned elements from that array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = ('hello', 'world');
my $joined = join ':', splice @array, 0, 3; # hello:world
# @array is now empty
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because IMO the arrays (undef, undef, undef) and (undef, undef) **should** result in "::" ":", correspondingly, which is clearly indicating that these were different inputs.

Comment: @zdim's answer also allows this as it's based on array size (but head/tail are the only easy solution for arbitrary lists without assigning to an array).

Answer (score 4):

Can also check the array size and join what you want, or the whole array

```
my $joined = join ':', (@ary > 3 ? @ary[0..2] : @ary);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [`grep`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to filter out values that are `undef`.

```
my $b = join(":", grep defined, @a[0..2]);
```

Note that this will allow values with the empty string `q{}`.

Comment: If you can't filter out `undef`, then you could use `@a[ grep $_ < @a, 0..2 ]`